# N4 test question「いろいろな花が______ゆうめいです」

Tags: grammar, jlpt

Part of a text says the following:

> もみじ山は、春、夏、秋、冬、きせつによって、いろいろな花が______　ゆうめいです。

The correct answer is さくことで but I chose さいているところで.  My book explains that for the latter to be correct it would have to be ところとしてゆうめい so that 'it can go with the subject もみじ山は'

I have no idea why one is correct and the other isn't.  I was hoping somebody might be able to throw some light on it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 「Phrase/Mini-Sentence + **こと** + **で** + ゆうめい + だ/です, etc.」 means:
>
> "to be famous **for the fact** that (phrase/mini-sentence)"

This is why 「～～いろいろな花がさく**ことで**ゆうめいです」 is grammatical and natural-sounding.

It is, however, **ungrammatical** to say:

「Phrase/Mini-Sentence + **ところ** + **で** + ゆうめい + だ/です, etc.」

just as it is ungrammatical in English to say "to be famous **for** the place where (phrase/mini-sentence)".

You would want to say "to be famous **as** the place where (mini-sentence)", wouldn't you?  (If I sound as if I were trying to teach English, that is not my intention.  In fact, I do not know much English.)

Thus, in Japanese, too, it is only correct to say:

> 「ところ + **と** + **して** + ゆうめい + だ/です, etc.」

"famous ***as*** the place where ~~~"